# iTextPDF export from Swing (JFreeChart) swallows specific unicode characters

Tags: unicode, fonts, itext, jfreechart

I just realised that iTextPDF swallowed some unicode characters when rendering a chart. I used a signum of histograms like this:

```
val sig = if (bin < 0) "\u2212" else if (bin > 0) "+" else ""
```

The chart is rendered with JFreeChart and exported through the PDFGraphics2D class of iTextPDF. The minus sign (which I chose because the hyphen `-` is too short) is swallowed in the output PDF. The font used is Helvetica, so there shouldn't be a mapping problem. Screenshot from Swing:

[image]

And here the PDF in Preview:

[image]

The characters are spaced out to make up for the missing minus character. What is the problem here? Font mapping?

Comment: So minus `\u2212` doesn't work, also not figure dash `\u2012`. I could make n-dash `\u2013` work, but for my taste it is a bit exaggerated (and minus would be the correct character).

Comment: *The font used is Helvetica, so there shouldn't be a mapping problem.* - quite to the contrary,  there most likely is the problem. Helvetica is one of the 14 standard fonts for PDF viewers, but these standard fonts only need to be supported for a limited character set,  cf. the specification ISO 32000-1.

Comment: So how would I go about this? Do I need to set up a specific font mapper?

Comment: Most likely, yes. I have not yet used the `Graphics2D` interface of iText intensively, though, so I can't help with this. @BrunoLowagie might have an idea.